# Constraints reactivate when contextMenu appears

Tags: ios, swift, uicollectionview, autolayout, uicontextmenuconfiguration

I am using UIContextMenuConfiguration for actions on a collection view cell. Everything works exactly as expected, however if my cell has (de)activated constraints from nib, it refreshes upon long press.

To demonstrate the problem, I have created a new project, with a `collectionView` in the storyboard. A custom cell in the collection view has a label with two constraints, a constraint pinning it to the bottom of the cell (**initially active**), and the other aligns it in the center (**initially disabled**).

Here's my code,

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource, UICollectionViewDelegateFlowLayout {
    
    func numberOfSections(in collectionView: UICollectionView) -> Int {
        return 1
    }
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return 10
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "cell", for: indexPath) as! CollectionViewCell
        cell.configure()
        return cell
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, contextMenuConfigurationForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath, point: CGPoint) -> UIContextMenuConfiguration? {
        return UIContextMenuConfiguration.init(identifier: nil, previewProvider: nil) { (array) -> UIMenu? in
            return UIMenu(title: "Hello", image: nil, identifier: nil, options: .destructive, children: [UIAction(title: "Share", image: UIImage(systemName: "tray.and.arrow.up"), identifier: nil) { _ in
                print("HelloWorld!")
              }])
        }
    }
    
    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {
        return CGSize(width: 265, height: 128)
    }
}

class CollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {

    @IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    @IBOutlet weak var centerConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
    
    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    func configure() {
        bottomConstraint.isActive = false
        centerConstraint.isActive = true
    }
}
```

[image: Initial state]
[image: Context menu presentation]
[image: After context menu dismissal]

Comment: You need to provide a little more detail. Quick test with your code, and I'm not seeing the results you are getting.

Comment: Oh, thanks for letting me know, is the information sufficient now?

Comment: Do you ***want*** the label to drop to the bottom when the context menu is shown?

Comment: No I don't (I want it to remain as it was before the context menu presentation) but when the context menu is shown, it seems that the framework implicitly reactivates the constraint that I have de activated for some reason.

Comment: I think you're asking for trouble with that approach. Setting `.isActive` on Storyboard created constraints is generally not a good idea. What are you trying to do that would require that?

Comment: Okay, so I am developing a chatting screen, and trying to achieve a whatsapp like behavior i.e. for a large message, the time label sticks to the bottom and for a shorter message it aligns itself in the center. There are other more complex behaviors in case of media attachments without caption that I am trying to achieve using this activating and deactivating constraints. I would love to know any better way of doing it, or at least why `.isActive` on storyboard constraints is not a good idea.

Answer (score 1):

The issue appears to be directly related to:

- two constraints created in Storyboard which would conflict with each other
- setting one constraint to **Not Installed**
- **de-activating** the *installed* constraint and **activating** the *not-installed* constraint

When initializing `UIContextMenuConfiguration` with `previewProvider: nil` - which tells UIKit to ***auto-generate*** a preview view - the "installed" states of the constraints are reset.

One way to get around it:

Instead of marking the Center constraint "not installed" give it a Priority of 998, and give the Bottom constraint a Priority of 999 (that will prevent IB from complaining).

You can then keep your `configure()` func as:

```
func configure() {
    bottomConstraint.isActive = false
    centerConstraint.isActive = true
}
```

and the label's centerY constraint will remain active in both the cell and in the context menu's preview.

However, **if you *WANT*** the previewView to look different than the cell, your best bet (and probably a better approach to begin with) is to use a custom `previewProvider`.

Comment: When initializing `UIContextMenuConfiguration` with `previewProvider: nil` - which tells `UIKit` to auto-generate a preview view - the "installed" states of the constraints are reset. Can you elaborate on this, I mean how does UIKit keeps everything in place but only resets the 'installed' states of constraints. Also, the solution you proposed has a slightly different impact then what I want. The functionality of the `configure` function would not have any impact on the context menu preview and the auto-layout will try to satisfy both constraints simultaneously, resulting in an enlarged label.

Comment: Basically, your presumption about the conflicting constraints is slightly misleading, because the constraints might not be conflicting but they are intended to be activated in a mutually exclusive fashion.

Comment: *the "installed" states of the constraints are reset* ... this is from observation. Using `Debug View Hierarchy` we can easily see that UIKit is using the 'installed' state of the Storyboard-set constraints. By *"conflicting constraints"* I meant if they are both **active** - it doesn't matter if your code is going to set them mutually exclusive at some point.

Comment: I had asked *"Do you want the label to drop to the bottom when the context menu is shown?"* and you said no... but it sounds like you **do** want the preview to look different than the cell. In that case, you will be way better off using your own `previewProvider` -- or, at least, *not* trying to use un-installed constraints.

Comment: Oh no. Sorry for the confusion and Thank you so much for trying to help me out. Basically, I am looking for a context menu that should look exactly like the cell. However the cell can appear in different states (different set of installed constraints). And regarding the "conflicting constraints" thing, I wanted to highlight the fact that in our current example setting both of them *active* would take the view in a different state instead of showing a conflicting constraints warning because UIKit will simultaneously satisfy both of them by increasing the label's height (not the intended output)

Comment: OK - it's either "bug" or an "unintended consequence"  but you've come across an issue with adding constraints in IB and marking them "not installed." Note that, in your example, if you leave **both** constraints **Installed**, you may get complaints from IB, but you **will** get your desired results at run-time.